# Use Python to send Line Notify with message and file

Tags: python-3.x, http-headers, line

I wrtoe a python to send message and png file to Line Notify.
It is work when not to set content-type,but when i set the content-type = 'multipart/form-data',it return '400'.
It also work when use curl and set the content-type = 'multipart/form-data'.
So what is the correct content-type Line Notify accept?

```
headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
        # "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        # "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data"
    }

    payload = {'message': msgs}
    imgs = {'imageFile': open('imgpath.png' , 'rb')}
    r = requests.post("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", headers = headers, data = payload, files = imgs)
```

```
curl -X POST -i https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "message=test" -F "imageFile=@C:\xxx.png"
```

It should return 200.